# my first WCF Server - received InvalidOperatonException. .NET claims that ServiceContract attribute is missing

Tags: c#, wcf

```
public interface IConsoleData
{
    double GetCurrentIndicator();
}

public class IConsoleDataImpl : IConsoleData
{
    public double GetCurrentIndicator()
    {
        return 22;
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMBClientConsole
{
    [OperationContract]
    IConsoleData GetData();
}

public class MBClientConsole : IMBClientConsole
{
    public IConsoleData GetData()
    {
        return new IConsoleDataImpl();
    }
}

class Log
{

    public static void initialize()
    {
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MBClientConsole),
          new Uri[]{
      new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")
    }))
        {
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MBClientConsole),
              new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
              "PipeReverse");

            host.Open();
            // TODO: host.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And when `AddServiceEndpoint` is called I receive

> The contract type Commons.MBClientConsole is not attributed with
>   ServiceContractAttribute.  In order to define a valid contract, the
>   specified type (either contract interface or service class) must be
>   attributed with ServiceContractAttribute.

But as you can see from my code interface is attributed with ServiceContract attribute. Why VS claims that it doesn't and how to fix the problem?

Updated listing below:

```
public interface IConsoleData
{
    double GetCurrentIndicator();
}

public class IConsoleDataImpl : IConsoleData
{
    public double GetCurrentIndicator()
    {
        return 22;
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMBClientConsole
{
    [OperationContract]
    IConsoleData GetData();
}

public class MBClientConsole : IMBClientConsole
{
    public IConsoleData GetData()
    {
        return new IConsoleDataImpl();
    }
}

class Log
{

    private ServiceHost _host;

    public void initialize()
    {
        _host = new ServiceHost(typeof (MBClientConsole),
                                new Uri[]
                                    {
                                        new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")
                                    });
            _host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMBClientConsole),
              new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
              "PipeReverse");

            _host.Open();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000000);
            // TODO: host.Close();
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public interface IConsoleData
{
    double GetCurrentIndicator();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMBClientConsole
{
    [OperationContract]
    IConsoleData GetData();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChannelFactory<IMBClientConsole> pipeFactory =
            new ChannelFactory<IMBClientConsole>(
                new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                new EndpointAddress(
                    "net.pipe://localhost/PipeReverse"));

        IMBClientConsole pipeProxy =
          pipeFactory.CreateChannel();

        while (true)
        {
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("pipe: " +
              pipeProxy.GetData().GetCurrentIndicator());
        }
    }
}
```

I still receive CommunicationException "There was an error reading from the pipe: The channel was closed. (109, 0x6d)."

Comment: Changed the title because, clearly, Visual Studio has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MBClientConsole),
              new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
              "PipeReverse");
```

to

```
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMBClientConsole),
              new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
              "PipeReverse");
```

the second needs the Service-Contract (=Interface) not the implementation. Sometimes they are the same but not here.

With

```
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MBClientConsole),
  new Uri[]{new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")}))
```

you say WCF what "object" to create (`MBClientConsole`) when the service is called (and the base-Address of the service) but with the `AddServiceEndpoint` you tell WCF what Service-Contract to expose. I hope you can make any sense from that ;)

You have a bug in your code:

```
public static void initialize()
{
    using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MBClientConsole),
      new Uri[]{new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")}))
    {
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMBClientConsole),
          new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
          "PipeReverse");

        host.Open();
        // TODO: host.Close();
    }
}
```

since you are using `using(Service host ...` the host object will be disposed if you leef the Initialize-Method. I guess you copied this from a ConsoleHost-Example. Move the host into a field and use something like this:

```
class Log
{

    ServiceHost _host;
    public void Initialize()
    {
      _host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MBClientConsole),
          new Uri[]{new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")});

      _host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMBClientConsole),
              new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
              "PipeReverse");

      _host.Open();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
       _host.Close();
       _host.Dispose();
    }
}
```

REMARKS: you made everything static (copied as I said) - I removed this. You might even think about implementing IDisposable (recommended) but I will leave this to your. You have to use this slightly different like

```
var log = new Log();
log.Initialize();
```

and before quiting your program:

```
log.Close();
```

Comment: thanks now I can run application, however communication still doesn't work, I receive such exception, probably i should create another topic for that... There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/PipeReverse that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Comment: {"The pipe endpoint 'net.pipe://localhost/PipeReverse' could not be found on your local machine. "}

Comment: well the way you used your ServiceHost in the method (using) it will get deleted as soon as the method leaves .. I will add this in my answer

Comment: now I receive CommunicationException "There was an error reading from the pipe: The channel was closed. (109, 0x6d)."

Comment: btw it doesn't launch with your code, I have to write `_host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMBClientConsole)` to get it started

Comment: of course... I copied your original class again ... doh - but the closed thing is because you shall call my .Close-method only before exiting your hosting application - just remove it for now.

Comment: I changed the code - sorry the using thing was buging me (I did not copy and compile)

Comment: I posted updated code in the original body, still receive CommunicationException...

Comment: if I change interface from `IConsoleData GetData();` to `string GetData();` everything works fine. So it seems I should do some extra work for custom types?